# How to use .net core version v3.1.0-preview1 on VS 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

After installing [v3.1.0-preview1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-3.1.100-preview1-windows-x64-installer) on my machine, when wanted to create a project this version of .net core is not on the .net core list on my Vsiual studio (2019 latest update).

I installed both x64 and x32 version of .net core v3.1.0-preview1 from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

How to fix this or use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to try the .NET Core preview version is to also use the [Visual Studio 2019 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en-us/vs/preview/)

Check [Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise Preview - Version 16.4.0 Preview 2.0](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en-us/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=enterprise&ch=pre&rel=16)

You can use the Visual Studio Enterprise, from preview channel, side-by-side with your other Visual Studio edition and version.